# if condition in bash scripting

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file that I want to check some line as below

```
com1=`awk 'NF{a=b;b=$0} END{print (b ~ /\com/)? "Yes" : "No"}' $myfile`
com2=`awk 'NF{a=b;b=$0} END{print (b ~ /\t/)? "Yes" : "No"}' $myfile`
com3=`awk 'NF{a=b;b=$0} END{print (a ~ /\t/)? "Yes" : "No"}' $myfile`
echo "$com1 --- $comp2 --- $comp3"
if [[ $comp1="Yes" ]] && [[ $comp3="No" ]]; then
    echo "condition1"
fi
if [[ $comp1="Yes" ]] && [[ $comp3="Yes" ]]; then
    echo "condition2" 
fi
if [[ $comp2="Yes" ]]; then
    echo "condition3"
fi
```

myfile is:

```
1.1.m
1.2.t

com
```

The output is"

```
Yes --- No --- No
condition1
condition2
condition3
```

I have two questions. at first: I want to check the non-blank line before last line of text file ( 1.2.t) that consist of "t" or not. so the answer 0f $com3 should be "Yes" but in my output is "NO". and the most important problem is none of 'if conditions' works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[ $comp1 = "Yes" ]] && [[ $comp3 = "No" ]]
```